# Insert "-- Select a Project -- " in a dropdown box

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a dropdown box in my asp.net web page. I want the dd box to start out on load with "-- Select a Project --" as the text value. The dd box is bound to an EF object at design time -- no custom code (sorry). It has (like a classic Combo Box) an "ID" column (integer) and a display column. When I had a dd box with only one column, the process was simple:

```
protected void ProjectDropDown_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        DropDownList list = sender as DropDownList; 
        if (list != null) 
            list.Items.Insert(0, "--Select a Project--"); 
    }
```

Here is an image of the EF Datasource:
[image]

And Here's an image of the DropDownBox Properties...[ID is an Integer, ProjectNbr is a string]....:
[image]

And, since that's hard to read, here's a close-up: 
[image]

But that doesn't work with a two-element dropdown box. Can anyone give me a hand?

Comment: What "two-element" do you want to display? Could you put an example?

Answer (score 0):

Use the ListControl.AppendDataBoundItems Property and set it to true:

[AppendDataBoundItems Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.appenddatabounditems.aspx)

From the documentation: "The AppendDataBoundItems property allows you to add items to the ListControl object before data binding occurs. After data binding, the items collection contains both the items from the data source and the previously added items."

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
protected void ProjectDropDown_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    DropDownList list = sender as DropDownList; 
    if (list != null) 
        list.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select a Project--","")); 
}
```